# Skewing an array in Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I have a 2D array that I will save as a grayscale image using `scipy.misc.toimage()`. Before doing so, I want to skew the image by a given angle, interpolating like `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate()`:

[image]

The image above is just to illustrate the skewing process. I am aware that I have to enlarge my image in order to contain the skewed version. How can I achieve this? I would prefer to use scipy for this.

Comment: This begs the question, why not just use `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate()`?

Comment: @DrBwts Can `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate()` do this? I don't want to rotate the whole image, I want to skew it such that only on of the axes is rotated.

Comment: my apologies I misread your post, have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191545/skewing-or-shearing-an-image-in-python) see if it helps.

Comment: PIL  has shear/skew capabilities. Look up PIL Affine transformations

Comment: An example for PIL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177744/how-does-perspective-transformation-work-in-pil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script can do that.

```
a=imread("sorNB.png")
h,l=a.shape
dl=50
b=numpy.zeros((h,l+dl),dtype=a.dtype)
for y in range(h):
    dec=(dl*(h-y))//h
    b[y,dec:dec+l]=a[y,:]
```

Since the inner  assignment  `(b[y,dec:dec+l]=a[y,:])` is pure numpy, this is very fast.

EDIT

thanks to ivan_pozdeev. a way for interpolation :

```
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import geometric_transform
a=imread("sorNB.png")
h,l=a.shape
def mapping(lc):
    l,c=lc
    dec=(dl*(l-h))/h
    return l,c+dec
figure(1)    
dl=50;c=geometric_transform(a,mapping,(h,l+dl),order=5,mode='nearest')
imshow (concatenate((a,zeros((225,50)),c),axis=-1),cmap=cm.gray)
```

[image: sof]

Comment: From the looks of it, this doesn't do sub-pixel interpolation. Thus the "saw" pattern on the skewed lines.

Comment: Yes, as @ivan_pozdeev pointed out it does not interpolate. However, I might need this for certain other applications. Thank you for the input!